# Como é avaliada esta expressão 'a' <= c <= 'z' no Python

Tags: python, característica-linguagem

Gostaria de saber a ordem de avaliação desta expressão no Python:

```
if 'a' <= c <= 'z': # c é uma variável de tipo `chr`
    print("Ronal... D'oh!")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ela é avaliada da esquerda pra direita, como se fosse:

```
'a' <= c and c <= 'z'
```

Além disso, se `c` fosse uma expressão com efeitos colaterais, tipo

```
a() <= c() <= z()
```

A chamada a `c()` só ocorreria uma única vez, ainda na ordem esquerda pra direita, i.e. depois de `a()` e antes de `z()`. [Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/101945/520779).

Outro exemplo:

```
>>> def a():
...   print('a')
...   return 'a'
...
>>> def z():
...   print('z')
...   return 'z'
...
>>> if a() <= 'c' <= z():
...   print('ok')
...
a
z
ok
>>> if a() <= 'A' <= z():
...   print('ok')
...
a
>>>
```

Note que como nesse último caso a primeira comparação deu `False`, a segunda não foi realizada (curto-circuito).